# How does the event handling in javascript work?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

First I'm sorry, because I'm certain that this has been asked many times, I just don't know how to search for this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <button type="button" onclick="hello()">test1</button>
            <button type="button" id="test2">test2</button>
            <h1 id='myText'></h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hello() {
                document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'test1';
            }
            document.getElementById('test2').onclick = function(event) {
                document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'test2';
            }   
        </script>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code. Before this version the whole script-tag was within the head area, and only `test1` worked, `test2` did nothing.

1. Can you point me on where to read up on why that is so?
2. Also, is there a preferred method of the two, to trigger an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the order in which the elements are processed.

In very simple terms: stuff in `<head>` loads up before the stuff in `<body>`, likewise, stuff at the top of `<body>` will load before stuff at the end of `<body>`. For this reason, where you're trying to grab an element with an ID of *test2*, your `#test2` event handler will only work when the `#test2` button has been loaded before your `<script>`; otherwise it simply doesn't exist on the page at this point.